# Price Book Entry History Report

Tags: custom-report-type, pricebook, pricebookentry

Is there no report capability to see the Price Book Entry History? I need to be able to report on what date a certain Product changed price in a certain Price Book and what it changed FROM/TO. I also noticed that in "Lightning" you can't even see the Price Book Entry History section. You have to jump back to "Classic".

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_sales_features_core_pricebook_entries_track_changes.htm&type=5&release=222 - when you turn on Field History Tracking on an object, a new Report Type will show up.

Comment: I have Field History Tracking on. That's why I can see it in "Classic" but I don't see a Report Type that would show that History. The closest I can get is a new Report of Price Books with Price Book Entries. Still no History of the prices being changed anywhere. There is a Last Modified Date and User but no From Price x To Price y. Thanks!