# Historical price list for Products?

Tags: sales-cloud, pricebook, pricebookentry

Historical price list for Products?

Hi,  I'm trying to find historical price list for Products? It that possible? All I'm able to find are current prices.  Thank you

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/363182/price-book-entry-history-report

Answer (score 0):

Price list association to products are not versioned objects. Try using Field history tracking to address the requirement. As I remember there is 24 months age limitation of storing the history transaction

Try using custom solutions with custom objects/automation to store this; to overcome any system limitations.

Please check any appexchange specific solutions as well.